# How to decode base64-encoded json object string in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a JSON object `X`

```js
var X = {
  'a': 'A',
  'b': 'B'
}
```

I am encoding the above object using `btoa()` in client-side Javascript

```js
var getEncryptedPayload = function(payload) { // payload is a JSON object
  payload = JSON.stringify(payload)
  payload = window.btoa(payload)
  return payload;
}
```

I want to decode the above encoded string in nodejs. I have tried to decode using `Buffer`, but not getting the result.

```js
var getRequestBody = function(request) {
    const encodedRequestBody = request.body;
    const decodedRequestBodyString = Buffer.from(encodedRequestBody, "base64");
    const requestBodyObject = JSON.parse(decodedRequestBodyString);
    return requestBodyObject;
}
```

But, the above code is throwing an error -

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Object

Could anyone please suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The result from `Buffer.from` is an instance of `Buffer`. To transform that buffer instance into a string that can be used in `JSON.parse` the code needs to invoke `Buffer.toString` first to make it work

```js
const requestBodyObject = JSON.parse(decodedRequestBodyString.toString());
```